# separate columns of a text file

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk

Hii experts i have a big text file that contain many columns.Now i want to extract each column in separate text file serially with adding two strings on the top.

suppose i have a input file like this

```
2 3 4 5 6 
3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6
1 2 2 2 2
```

then i need to extract each column in separate text file with  two strings on the top

```
file1.txt      file2.txt     .... filen.txt

s=5            s=5
r=9            r=9
2              3
3              4
2              3
1              2
```

i tried script as below:but it doesnot work properly.need help from experts.Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 1 1 5)

do
echo $i
awk '{print $i}' inp_file  > file_$i
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Following doesn't have `close` file function used because your sample shows you have only 5 columns in Input_file. Also created 2 `awk` variables which will be printed before actual column values are getting printed to output file(named `var1` and `var2`).

```
awk -v var1="s=5" -v var2="r=9" '
{
  count++
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    outputFile="file"i".txt"
    if(count==1){
      print (var1 ORS var2) > (outputFile)
    }
    print $i > (outputFile)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

In case you can have more than 5 or more columns then better close output files kin backend using `close` option, use this then(to avoid error `too many files opened`).

```
awk -v var1="s=5" -v var2="r=9" '
{
  count++
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    outputFile="file"i".txt"
    if(count==1){
      print (var1 ORS var2) > (outputFile)
    }
    print $i >> (outputFile)
  }
  close(outputFile)
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple to do in one pass through the file with `awk` using its output redirection:

```sh
awk 'NR==1 { for (n = 1; n <= NF; n++) print "s=5\nr=9" > ("file_" n) }
     { for (n = 1; n <= NF; n++) print $n > ("file_" n) }' inp_file
```

Comment: Note that in some awk this is a syntax error, and you need to write `print $n > ("file_" n)`

Comment: It will also fail with a "too many open files" error once you get past about a dozen output files unless you're using GNU awk and then it'll just start to run slower.

Comment: @EdMorton A dozen files? What kind of ulimit settings do you work under?

Comment: If you think that should be a different number, feel free to substitute that number and the issue still applies.

Comment: @EdMorton A thousand+? Not too worried about it.

Comment: No, some other number less than 20.

Comment: I just tested with the BSD awk on MacOS and it failed there after creating the 17th output file. Maybe you're thinking of the max args possible rather than max open files?

Comment: @EdMorton Again, what sort of low ulimit settings are you forced to work under that you can only have that many open files?

Comment: if you have a specific command in mind that you'd like me to run, feel free to share what that command is and I'll post the result. This isn't just my problem, it's a common issue.

Comment: @EdMorton Er... `ulimit -a` or `ulimit -n` for just the maximum number of open files a process can have. Surprised you don't know about it.

Comment: `ulimit -a` and `ulimit -n` on the same box both output 256. Which command did you want me to run to tell us how many open files that awk command can have? Sorry for not knowing it.

Comment: So bump up the limit? Works fine with a lot more columns than that with GNU awk, NetBSD awk, OpenBSD awk, mawk...

Comment: "Bump up the limit" how exactly? That's a rhetorical question as it's not reasonable to expect everyone to do whatever it is. You seem to think this is an issue just for me on my box - it's not, it's a common issue with non-gawk awks (see the result of https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+too+many+open+files) and it has the well-known solution of closing the files as you go.

Comment: When my code works on more different implementations of awk than I can shake a stick at and one person claims there's a problem... it's not a problem with my code, but their setup. And when they seem to be intentionally dense... got, I hate SO sometimes.

Comment: What are you talking about??? This is an extremely common problem, just look at all the google search results. Feel free to stick your head in the sand if you like though.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk to internally handle more than a dozen or so simultaneously open files:

```
NR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        out[i] = "file" i ".txt"
        print "s=5" ORS "r=9" > out[i]
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print $i > out[i]
    }
}
```

or with any awk just close them as you go:

```
NR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        out[i] = "file" i ".txt"
        print "s=5" ORS "r=9" > out[i]
        close(out[i])
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print $i >> out[i]
        close(out[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`split -nr/$(wc -w <(head -1 input) | cut -d' ' -f1) -t' ' --additional-suffix=".txt" -a4 --numeric-suffix=1  --filter "cat <(echo -e 's=5 r=9') - | tr ' ' '\n' >\$FILE" <(tr -s '\n' ' ' <input) file`

This uses the nifty `split` command in a unique way to rearrange the columns. Hopefully it's faster than `awk`, although after spending a considerable amount of time coding it, testing it, and writing it up, I find that it may not be scalable enough for you since it requires a process per column, and many systems are  limited in user processes (check `ulimit -u`). I submit it though because it may have some limited learning usefulness, to you or to a reader down the line.

Decoding:

`split` -- Divide a file up into subfiles. Normally this is by lines or by size but we're tweaking it to use columns.

`-nr/$(...)` -- Use round-robin output: Sort records (in our case, matrix cells) into the appropriate number of bins in a round-robin fashion. This is the key to making this work. The part in parens means, count (`wc`) the number of words (`-w`) in the first line (`<(head -1 input)`) of the input and discard the filename (`cut -d' ' -f1`), and insert the output into the command line.

`-t' '` -- Use a single space as a record delimiter. This breaks the matrix cells into records for `split` to split on.

`--additional-suffix=".txt"` -- Append `.txt` to output files.

`-a4` -- Use four-digit numbers; you probably won't get 1,000 files out of it but just in case ...

`--numeric-suffix=1` -- Add a numeric suffix (normally it's a letter combination) and start at 1. This is pretty pedantic but it matches the example. If you have more than 100 columns, you will need to add a `-a4` option or whatever length you need.

`--filter ...` -- Pipe each file through a shell command.

Shell command:

`cat` -- Concatenate the next two arguments.

`<(echo -e 's=5 r=9')` -- This means execute the echo command and use its output as the input to `cat`. We use a space instead of a newline to separate because we're converting spaces to newlines eventually and it is shorter and clearer to read.

`-` -- Read standard input as an argument to `cat` -- this is the binned data.

`| tr ' ' '\n'` -- Convert spaces between records to newlines, per the desired output example.

`>\$FILE` -- Write to the output file, which is stored in `$FILE` (but we have to quote it so the shell doesn't interpret it in the initial command).

Shell command over -- rest of `split` arguments:

`<(tr -s '\n' ' ' < input)` -- Use, as input to `split`, the example input file but convert newlines to spaces because we don't need them and we need a consistent record separator. The `-s` means only output one space between each record (just in case we got multiple ones on input).

`file` -- This is the prefix to the output filenames. The output in my example would be `file0001.txt`, `file0002.txt`, ..., `file0005.txt`.